# How to check if user if banned using PHP function

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function which I can call on each page so it checks if the user has been banned.

```
1 = banned
0 = not banned
```

my function:

```
public function not_banned()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
        $status = $stmt -> fetch();
        if ($status == "0"){
            return true;
        } else {
            session_destroy();
            unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

When I call the function and when my status is 0 it still destroys my session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
$status = $stmt -> fetch();
```

[`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns an array containing all of the fields for a single row of the result set.  You then can access each field (in this case) by name...

```
if ($status['status'] == "0"){
```

Answer (score 0):

if the user is banned return true else return false

```
public function is_banned()
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = :user_id");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_session']));
        $status = $stmt -> fetch();
        if ($status['status'] == "0"){
            return false;
        } else {
            unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
            session_destroy();
            return true;
        }
    }
```